# Does MySQL cache by default

Tags: mysql, caching

Does MySQL cache queries by default or does it only cache when the `SQL_CACHE` keyword is used in the query? What other things should I keep in mind when using MySQL caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The have_query_cache server system variable indicates whether the
>   query cache is available:
>
> mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache'; | Variable_name    |
>   Value | | have_query_cache | YES   | When using a standard MySQL
>   binary, this value is always YES, even if query caching is disabled.
>
> Several other system variables control query cache operation. These
>   can be set in an option file or on the command line when starting
>   mysqld. The query cache system variables all have names that begin
>   with query_cache_. They are described briefly in Section 5.1.3,
>   “Server System Variables”, with additional configuration information
>   given here.
>
> To set the size of the query cache, set the query_cache_size system
>   variable. Setting it to 0 disables the query cache. The default size
>   is 0, so the query cache is disabled by default.
>
> Be careful not to set the size of the cache too large. Due to the need
>   for threads to lock the cache during updates, you may see lock
>   contention issues with a very large cache.

Quote taken from the MySQL Site http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html